# No Known Conversion for SFML Vector2i

Tags: c++, arrays, networking, game-engine, sfml

I'm completely burned out on this one, but why am I getting:

```
client.cpp: In member function 'void Client::netRead(int, int)':
client.cpp:158:57: error: no matching function for call to 'Client::nextGameUpdate(sf::Vector2i [0], int [0], sf::IpAddress [0], int&)'
client.cpp:158:57: note: candidate is:
client.cpp:85:6: note: void Client::nextGameUpdate(sf::Vector2i, int, sf::IpAddress, int)
client.cpp:85:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'sf::Vector2i [0] {aka sf::Vector2<int> [0]}' to 'sf::Vector2i {aka sf::Vector2<int>}'
[Finished in 4.7s]
```

---

```
    void Client::nextGameUpdate(sf::Vector2i qq, int ww, sf::IpAddress cc, int dataSize)
    {
        pListIP[dataSize] = cc;
        pListVec[dataSize] = qq;
        pListRot[dataSize] = ww;

        int num_pListIP = sizeof(pListIP)/sizeof(sf::IpAddress);
        if (num_pListIP == lastPlayerCount)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (num_pListIP > lastPlayerCount)
        {
            int new_players = num_pListIP - lastPlayerCount;
            for (new_players; new_players>0; new_players--)
            {
                addPlayer();


}
    }
    else if (num_pListIP < lastPlayerCount)
    {
        int dc_players = lastPlayerCount - num_pListIP;
        for (dc_players; dc_players>0; dc_players--)
        {
            removePlayer();
        }
    }
    lastPlayerCount = num_pListIP;
}

void Client::netRead(int net_step, int dataSize)
{
    sf::Packet player_vectors;
    sf::Packet player_rotations;
    sf::Packet player_ips;

    switch (net_step)
    {
        case 1:
            if (socket.receive(player_vectors, sender, senderPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
                return;
            while (dataSize>0)
            {
                sf::Vector2i tmp_vec;
                player_vectors >> tmp_vec.x >> tmp_vec.y;
                pListVec[dataSize] = tmp_vec;
                dataSize--;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (socket.receive(player_rotations, sender, senderPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
                return;
            while (dataSize>0)
            {
                int tmp_rot;
                player_rotations >> tmp_rot;
                pListRot[dataSize] = tmp_rot;
                dataSize--;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (socket.receive(player_ips, sender, senderPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
                return;
            while (dataSize>0)
            {
                std::string tmp_str;
                player_ips >> tmp_str;
                sf::IpAddress tmp_ips = tmp_str;
                pListIP[dataSize] = tmp_ips;
                dataSize--;
            }
            break;
    }
    nextGameUpdate(pListVec, pListRot, pListIP, dataSize);
}
```

---

Header

```
private:
sf::Vector2i pListVec[];
sf::IpAddress pListIP[];
int pListRot[];
```

I feel like it has something to do with the array I'm trying to fill with sf::Vector2i... */me stares blankly at screen*

So very simply put. netRead gets info from another function that is very basic. Then the switch goes through the net_step int...

After the game has received all the packets needed to continue, we trigger the nextGameUpdate() and send it 3 arrays and a dataSize int variable.

Thanks in advance if you figure this one out. ^^

Comment: Note: Uses the most recent version of 2.0 snapshot of SFML http://sfml-dev.org/

Comment: Where is the declaration of `pListVec` in `netRead`? If it is a class member or a file-level static variable, why are you passing it to the function?

Comment: Updated with the header declaration. This is network code so I'm receiving packets that fully update those arrays and then queue them in nextGameUpdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass `pListVec` into `qq` where the former is an array of `Vector2i` and the latter is a single `Vector2i`.

But there is also a bug in your logic. Substitute `pListVec` into `qq` in your update function, and the second statement reads:

`pListVec[dataSize] = pListVec;`

That cannot possibly be what you intended to do.

---

Also, since `pListVec` is a private field of your class, there is no need to pass it as an argument between member functions (at least in your case, where both methods are invoked on the same instance).